# Problems connecting to sqlserver instance

Tags: drivers

If i try to connect to sqlcmd like this:

sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1:1433 -U SA -P pass

I get ..

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

I'm afraid my driver is not properly installed, I've been reading google information about this problem and nothing works, however

nc -z -v -w5 127.0.0.1 1433
Connection to 127.0.0.1 1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!

..and
tsql -S 127.0.0.1 -U SA
Password: 
locale is "es_ES.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> 
..also works.

systemctl status mssql-server --no-pager

$ systemctl status mssql-server --no-pager
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-08 18:19:10 CEST; 3h 21min ago
     Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 25809 (sqlservr)
    Tasks: 154
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─25809 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─25856 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

ago 08 18:19:59 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [71B blob data]
ago 08 18:19:59 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [162B blob data]
ago 08 18:19:59 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [124B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:34 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [96B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:34 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [74B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:34 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [68B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:35 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [136B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:35 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [111B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:35 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [137B blob data]
ago 08 19:03:35 dpinalopez68-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12R sqlservr[25809]: [112B blob data]

....and finally

sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
[sudo] contraseña para dpinalopez68: 
systemd-r   909 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  22378      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20M  1908            root   60u  IPv6  31648      0t0  TCP *:32400 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20M  1908            root   61u  IPv4  31650      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:32401 (LISTEN)
smbd       2022            root   32u  IPv6  32325      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
smbd       2022            root   33u  IPv6  32326      0t0  TCP *:139 (LISTEN)
smbd       2022            root   34u  IPv4  32327      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
smbd       2022            root   35u  IPv4  32328      0t0  TCP *:139 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20S  2191            root    7u  IPv4  34705      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:38271 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20D  3555            root   15u  IPv4  38184      0t0  TCP *:1573 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20D  3555            root   33u  IPv4  37458      0t0  TCP *:32469 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20T  3574            root   13u  IPv4  37432      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:32600 (LISTEN)
cupsd      4881            root    6u  IPv6  47176      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      4881            root    7u  IPv4  47177      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
code      14120    dpinalopez68   78u  IPv4 441836      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:56103 (LISTEN)
sqlservr  25856           mssql  171u  IPv6 249437      0t0  TCP *:1433 (LISTEN)
sqlservr  25856           mssql  172u  IPv4 249438      0t0  TCP *:1433 (LISTEN)
sqlservr  25856           mssql  176u  IPv6 249441      0t0  TCP [::1]:1434 (LISTEN)
sqlservr  25856           mssql  179u  IPv4 249442      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1434 (LISTEN)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017), the proper way to explicitely set the port is `-S [protocol:]server[instance_name][,port]`, not `server:port` as you are doing it.

Also, since `1433` is the default port, and on your other ways to test it, you're excluding it, you can also remove it on the `sqlcmd` options.

I think this is the case because the error says `Server is not found or not accessible`. Nothing about the driver, so the wrong syntax is making the search for the host unsuccessful.